# Ruby on Rails convert date and time value properly formatted utc time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, utc

I have a date value like 2016-11-19 and a time value like 2000-01-01 20:14:00 +0000

I want to convert it to proper date format which will show utc time like below:
2016-11-20 04:14:00 +0000

There lots of questions regarding this, but I am confused.

Comment: Where does the `04` hour come from?

Comment: 04 does not matter here! What matters converting to local to utc time. I got the solution though. See my answer.

Comment: I am sorry, perhaps it is just me, but I still don't understand your problem. Both datetimes in your question are already in UTC, but they differ in day and hour. What is the rule for this difference? Since both datetime examples are already in UTC it seems like you want to shift the time +8 hours. Is that correct? Is that what you want? (Plus the combination of a time from a datetime and the date fraction from the date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone! But, I could solve the problem on my own!

```
time = bid_end_time.hour.to_s + ":" + bid_end_time.min.to_s + ":" + bid_end_time.sec.to_s
date_time = bid_end_date.to_s + " " + time
bid_end_date_time = Time.zone.parse(date_time).utc
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your date value to a time value:

```
>> date = Date.new(2016, 11, 19)
>> time = date.to_time
=> 2016-11-19 00:00:00 -0700
```

Note that `time` will be set to midnight in the time zone to which your server is set. Now that you have a time object, you can add seconds to it:

```
>> time_increment = Time.new(2000, 1, 1, 20, 14, 0)
>> seconds_increment = time_increment.seconds_since_midnight
=> 72840.0
>> new_time = time + seconds_increment
=> Sat, 19 Nov 2016 20:14:00 MST -07:00
```

Comment: You need to do this programmatically, as you are given two strings that need to be converted to objects. Also, the question asks that the UTC time be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ruby `strftime` datetime format.

Like

```
date_value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  #=> 24-hour clock

date_value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')  #=> 12-hour clock
```

[Full documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.